# MVC unobtrusive attributes based validation requires more than one click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using unobtrusive attributes based validation with MVC 4. I have a quite standard input form. At the beginning all fields are empty. I have a problem with select (drop down list). It's required field and failure scenario is following:

1. Click on empty form (validation triggers messages and red frames)
2. Select value in drop down list (validation message and frame is still visible; after clicking outside of drop down message is hiding but frame is not).
3. Click on submit button.

If user doesn't click outside after selecting value from drop down list it won't pass the validation until submit button is clicked twice. Though first click isn't a click but only "focus" lost on drop down list.

Is there any way to force, with jQuery or somehow, the page to lost focus on drop down list after selecting a value. I tried to execute jQuery's validate() on click of submit button and on select event on drop down list. Both with no result.

My partial view looks as follows:

```
@model EditVM

@{
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm(Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editForm" }))
{
<div class="sth_form">
        <div class="frm_row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FIELD1)
            <div class="frm_row_input">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FIELD1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD1)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FIELD2)
            <div class="frm_row_input">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FIELD2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD2)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_row" id="contractorHeaderRow">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR)
            <div class="frm_row_input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_row" id="contractorRow">
            <div class="frm_row_input" id="contractorDropDownList">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR, Model.Contractors)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text_rgt">
        <input type="submit" name="Save" value="@Model.LabelSave" />
        <input type="submit" name="Reset" value="@Model.LabelReset" />
    </div>
}
```

My view:

```
@model EditVM   

@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.Sth._Edit, Model)
```

My controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Insert()
{
    #region Preparing model

    var model = new EditVMBuilder().BuildInsert();
    PrepareBaseProperties(model);
    LoadDropDownListsForSth(model);

    #endregion
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Insert(EditVM model)
{
    if (Request.Form["Save"] != null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            #region Save

            Mapper.CreateMap<EditVM, SthModel>();
            SthModel sth = new SthModel();
            Mapper.Map(model, sth);
            _dataAccess.SthAdd(sth);
            _dataAccess.SaveChanges();

            #endregion
            #region Show result

            var resultMessage = string.Format(
                "{0}: {1}",
                Resources.ResultMessages.SomeMessage,
                model.FIELD1);
            model.ResultMessage = resultMessage;
            PrepareBaseProperties(model);

            #endregion
            return View(MVC.Shared.Views._Message, model);
        }
    }
    if (Request.Form["Reset"] != null)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        return this.Insert();
    }
    //Validation
    model = new EditVMBuilder().ConfigureInsert(model);
    PrepareBaseProperties(model);
    LoadDropDownListsForSth(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This is not the default behavior so you have something wrong with you code, but you haven't posted it.

Comment: I wasn't asking what's wrong with my code, but rather a method how explicitly call a validation, but you're right, it may help, so I've just posted my code.

Comment: You don't need to _explicitly call a validation_! If its not working then its a problem with your code.

Comment: I'd say it's working but not perfect, anyway can you see any problem with the code?

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code in your post action, what is `return this.Insert();` for example and why are you doing `model = new EditVMBuilder().ConfigureInsert(model);` - its pointless since ModelState values are already set. But I'm not sure these are the issue or not. All I can suggest is you put a breakpoint on the first line of your POST method and debug it to try and workout whats happening.

Comment: You're right, I stopped thinking about it some time ago, but I'm not enough aware about that mechanism. The thing I don't understand is when in case of reset I won't Clear the ModelState but only redirect to GET the view is getting an empty model but the values in the textboxes are still filled. On the other hand when I call ModelState.Clear() but won't redirect to GET the values are still filled but the validation messages disappear.

Comment: Builder is setting values not passed from the form, namely the view model settings like the action and controller bound to the save button, because the view is reusable and is used to insert and edit.

Comment: You have `model = new EditVMBuilder()...` which means its returning a new model which is not the right thing to do. You have too much here to fix. Work through a few tutorials and learn to do things the MVC way. Then if you have issues ask questions but narrow it down to specific issues, one at a time. (and you should never include properties such as `controller` and `edit` in a view model).

Comment: Why the controller and action names can't be stored in a view model? How can I obtain re-usability of a view if not by specifying which action should be executed on a button click?